# Двойное объявление переменнной

Tags: c

В main.c пишу так:

```
HWND  IdGlavOkna;
LRESULT CALLBACK ProcGlavOkna(HWND IdGlavOkna, UINT IdSbwn, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

Компилирую в CodeBlocks - ОК. Прога работает.

Потом комментирую первую строку:

```
//HWND  IdGlavOkna;
LRESULT CALLBACK ProcGlavOkna(HWND IdGlavOkna, UINT IdSbwn, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

Компилирую в CodeBlocks - ОК. Прога работает. Разницы между вариантом 1 и 2 не видно.
Поясните, пожалуйста, почему компилятор не ругался  на двойное определение переменной?
И главный вопрос - как **грамотно** написать этот код?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут нет никакого двойного определения переменной. Есть определение переменной и объявление функции с одноименным параметром, который никак на уровне языка не связан с внешней переменной. При этом в сях (но не в плюсах) разрешено многократно объявлять глобальную переменную без явного упоминания слова extern. Но к данному случаю это никак не относится.

Comment: Т.е. IdGlavOkna из первой строки - глобальная переменная,  а параметр функции IdGlavOkna - локальная, и они никак не связаны друг с другом? Правильно я полял?

Comment: @0Zerro внутри функции это будет локальная переменная, не связанная с глобальной.

Comment: *Объявлять* переменную (не определяя ее) можно и в С и в С++ сколько угодно раз. Подозреваю, что ваше последнее утверждение ссылается на tentative definitions языка С, но это именно definitiuons, т.е. *определения*.

Comment: @AnT **tentative definition** это хоть и определение, но предварительное. Такое же поведение в `c++` дает `extern`, и там это уже не является определением (только объявлением). В частности, не выделяет памяти для переменной. На этом и базировался мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Каждый идентификатор является видимым в определенной части программы, которая называется его областью видимости ( **scope** ). Один и тот же идентификатор может обозначать различные сущности, если эти сущности имеют различные области видимости или находятся в различных пространствах имен.

В C имеется четыре области видимости: область видимости функции, область видимости файла, область видимости блока и область видимости прототипа функции - объявления функции с указанием типов параметров.

А также в C  имеются следующие пространства имен: пространства имен меток, пространство имен тегов структур, объединений и перечислений, пространства имен членов структур и объединений, и пространство имен всех остальных идентификаторов. Можно объявлять одно и то же имя для различных сущностей, которые принадлежат различным пространствам имен (смотрите пример ниже).

Имя метки - это единственный тип идентификаторов, которые имеют область видимости функции.

Все остальные идентификаторы имеют область видимости, определяемую расположением объявления идентификатора.

Если объявление идентификатора находится вне любого блока или списка параметров функции, то идентификатор имеет область видимости файла.

Если объявление идентификатора размещено в каком-нибудь блоке или в списке параметров определения функции, то идентификатор имеет область видимости блока.

Если объявление идентификатора находится в списке параметров прототипа функции, то область видимости этого идентификатора - область видимости прототипа данной функции, которая ограничена объявлением прототипа.

Если для идентификаторов с одним и тем же именем, принадлежащих одному пространству имен, области видимости накладываются друг на друга, то идентификатор во вложенной (внутренней) области видимости скрывает идентификатор, объявленный во внешней (охватывающей) области видимости.

В вашем примере объявлений

```
HWND  IdGlavOkna;
LRESULT CALLBACK ProcGlavOkna(HWND IdGlavOkna, UINT IdSbwn, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

если эти объявления помещены вне любого блока, то идентификатор `IdGlavOkna` в первом объявлении имеет область видимости файла, а идентификатор с тем же именем `IdGlavOkna` в объявлении функции имеет область видимости прототипа этой функции, то есть этот идентификатор виден только внутри объявления списка параметров функции и скрывает идентификатор с тем же именем, объявленный в предыдущем объявлении перед объявлением функции.

Ниже показан демонстрационная программа, в которой приведены примеры объявлений различных сущностей с одним и тем же идентификатором но в разных областях видимости и пространствах имен.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct x
{
    int x;
};

struct x x = { 10 };

void f( struct x x );

void f( struct x x )
{
    goto x;
x:  printf( "In f x.x = %d\n", x.x );
}

int main( void )
{
    f( x );

    struct x
    {
        int x;
    } x = { 20 };        

    goto x;

x:  printf( "in main x.x = %d\n", x.x );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
In f x.x = 10
in main x.x = 20
```